# RSA Decryption, Finding the value of d without being allowed to do operations with fractions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For a Computer science homework assignment, I have to decrypt a small message which is encrypted with RSA. We are given the public key (e,N) that are small numbers and allow the factors p and q to be found easily. We need to find d so that,

(message)^d modulo N = (decrypted message).

I know that,

d = e^(-1) mod ((p-1)*(q-1)),

However, One of the rules of our homework assignment is that we can only use add, subtract, multiply, integer-division and modulo with two whole numbers.

We've tried the extended euclidean algorithm but our results aren't matching and are partly outside of the rage of values in the ASCII Table we have been told to use. Any suggestions as to what to do or what to read to better understand the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Modular inverse (when it exists) is unique, and absolutely should work. So if it takes you outside of the range then may be some part of the encoding process was described incorrectly (or incompletely). Is the encryption specified to be done one digit at a time, two digits at a time... or some other way. You do need to also observe such specs.

Comment: Do double check that the $(e,d)$ pair you have satisfies the congruence $de\equiv1\pmod{(p-1)(q-1)}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).